# Password iteration with no similar characters?

Tags: python

I was reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367900/4892914), and it inspired me to to some research how to optimize brute forcing on simple generated passwords.

## My encounter:

Im trying to iterate all available password combinations from `key=''.join(random.sample(string.uppercase, 7))`. And if i have read the docs right: `key` in this case, cannot consist of two similar, or equal, letters. It is always a (in this case) unique 7 long upper case string.

- example: `str(key)` **cannot** be generated: `AARGHJU`

## Question:

How to i change the while statement so it does not iterate over a a string containing similar letters?

```
chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ' # chars to look for
try:
    while 1:
        # Iteration processess of possibel keys
        for length in range(7,8): # only do length of 7
            to_attempt = product(chars, repeat=length)
            for attempt in to_attempt:
                print(''.join(attempt))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Keybord interrupt, exiting gracefully anyway."
    sys.exit()
```

Generating ex will produce unnecessary time and power:

```
AAAFXEL
AAAFXEM
AAAFXEN
AAAFXEO
AAAFXEP
AAAFXEQ
AAAFXER
AAAFXES
```

Comment: I don't understand where you got that requirement. Surely enforcing unique letters *reduces* the strength of a password, since it cuts the potential range of values for each successive letter?

Comment: Yes thats right. Maybe my updated question will shed some light over my problem

Comment: `for length in range(7,8)` this only outputs 7. So why are you using for there?

Comment: @Lafexlos can you please elaborate

Comment: have you checked the output of `range(7,8)`? That is a list/generator that contains only a number. 7. So why are you using `for` there, instead of just `length = 7`.

Comment: @Lafexlos So i change the length if i want to

Comment: I assume he wants the script to be modifiable to handle other lengths or indeed a range of lengths but for the purposes of this example has just hacked it to only do length 7. If you want a string of unique characters, make a set of all the letters in the alphabet then pop one at random each time?

Comment: Yeah, that's understandable. My bad to not see that.

Comment: [itertool.permutations()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) is what you are looking for but for this much of items, you'll most likely to get memoryError.

Comment: @Lafexlos please explain the memoryError i can expect. It seems that I generate one string, compare it to the other. Generate a new string, compare that. Where would the memory leak be? But thanks anyway

Comment: @Lafexlos, I see no memory problem unless you try to explicitly collect all combinations in a list or similar structure. `itertools.permutations` just "yields" values.

Comment: Yeah, don't mind me and just use permutations. Seems like my brain doesn't want to work today. Sorry about confusions.

Comment: Looks like @Lafexlos beat me to the permutations suggestion.  I didn't see comments until it reloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For non repeating enumeration of the entire space, perhaps you want itertools.permutations.

````
```python
from itertools import permutations
chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ' # chars to look for
try:
    while 1:
        # Iterate through possible keys
        for length in range(7,8):
            to_attempt = permutations(chars, length)
            for attempt in to_attempt:
                print(''.join(attempt))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Keyboard interrupt, exiting gracefully anyway."
    sys.exit()
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your answer! is it possible to start the permutations from a specific point? Let´s say i run the code for 10 minutes, and i end up at `ATJOIRE`. Is it then possible to "resume" from that point.

Comment: You could use `itertools.dropwhile`. Alternately you might construct your own implementation.