# Brute Force Script

Tags: python-3.x, brute-force

I am creating a simple brute force script, but I can't quite seem to figure it out. I am using the accepted answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367553/brute-force-script-in-python-3-2), but I can't get 'attempt' to equal the user password. Below is the code I have used (from the linked question), and changed it a little.

```
from string import printable
from itertools import product

user_password = 'hi' # just a test password
for length in range(1, 10): # it isn't reasonable to try a password more than this length
    password_to_attempt = product(printable, repeat=length)
    for attempt in password_to_attempt:
        if attempt == user_password:
            print("Your password is: " + attempt)
```

My code just runs until it hits the end of the Cartesian, and never prints the final answer. Not sure what is going on.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: What is the type of `attempt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) gives you a collection of *tuples* not strings.  So, you may eventually get the result `('h', 'i')`, but this is not the same as `'hi'`.

You need to combine the letters into a single string to compare.  Also, you should stop the program once you've found the password.

```
from string import printable
from itertools import product

user_password = 'hi' # just a test password
found = False

for length in range(1, 10): # it isn't reasonable to try a password more than this length
    password_to_attempt = product(printable, repeat=length)

    for attempt in password_to_attempt:
        attempt = ''.join(attempt) # <- Join letters together

        if attempt == user_password:
            print("Your password is: " + attempt)
            found = True
            break

    if found:
        break
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#bVCxboQwDN3zFdZ1ANRr1VtRWTt07tIJ5XoGcoUYOY6qfj01HBCd1AyJ4uf3/J6nhmmAIOx8C24YiQVG/Yg992gW0AmyEPUh4XSJX2JMDMj1aEP4Ib5ABVnnMniAawwCFgT12VDTUPRzz5vtAxr9MvToW@nAeWDrW8xPRzi9FKUqOAEXfCbAaAP52QsIgfCv6u4DB2Itd9br5cIqZ0DP1lIL1VYEh1F09Oo73/MdVX9EK9WNWpiFPFvbSOrtH61y6ZtPEs@y5ys5n6@VQlO8PsG7ltSY1jhoghalQzY73TVJoYK7daYZS6DZcn74pMgpvwslHOBxkyjuGNu@PzjiHXDWnX7fLOj4pS3NWsBp@gM)

Comment: I get the answer printed out (thanks for that!) but it still continues to loop through the entire Cartesian, even after I included the `break` at the end

Comment: @Goalieman: Yeah, I forgot there were 2 `for` loops (and that you can't use `break 2` in python).  I modified the answer a bit, try it now.

Comment: so this is using special characters, how about not using them?